# Replace one delimiter of string with another

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xslt element that takes the input as INDIA;JAPAN;CHINA;CANADA etc. I want the output to appear as INDIA,JAPAN,CHINA,CANADA. (i.e) i want to replace the dilimeter ";" with ","

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Replace spaces in a String with a different whitespace character in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662643/java-replace-spaces-in-a-string-with-a-different-whitespace-character-in)

Answer (score 0):

Use the translate() function:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate

Answer (score 0):

xslt 2.0 supports string replace function.